# SQL: Sequentially doing UPDATE .WRITE on VarBinary column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, varbinary

I'm trying to create a little test application which reads chunks of a FileStream and appends it to a VarBinary(max) column on an SQL Server 2005 Express.

Everything works - the column gets filled as it's supposed to, but my machine still seems to buffer everything into memory and I just can't see why.

I'm using the following code (C#):

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [BLOB] ([Id],[Data]) VALUES (@p1,0x0)";

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Value = id;
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    if (File.Exists(textBox1.Text))
    {
        using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE [BLOB] SET [Data].WRITE(@data, @offset, @len) WHERE [Id]=@id";

            SqlParameter dataParam = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            command.Parameters.Add(dataParam);

            SqlParameter offsetParam = new SqlParameter("@offset", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            command.Parameters.Add(offsetParam);

            SqlParameter lengthParam = new SqlParameter("@len", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            command.Parameters.Add(lengthParam);

            SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add(idParam);
            idParam.Value = id;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2090400]; //chunk sizes that are multiples of 8040 bytes.
                int read = 0;
                int offset = 0;

                while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    dataParam.Value = buffer;
                    offsetParam.Value = offset;
                    lengthParam.Value = read;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    offset += read;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why it buffers the file into memory? The `byte[]` buffer I'm using is only almost 2 MB in size.

I could create a new buffer for each chunk, but that seems like a waste of CPU/memory also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it buffers it because when you save it into the varbinary column it becomes part of the LOB data cache in sql server. that's how it works.

or do you mean it gets buffered somewhere else?

Comment: Well, I mean it buffers it into my machines memory. If I try to save a 1GB file to the column, it'll end up using 1GB of physical memory.
Since an SQL server doesn't keep all it's content in RAM, I'm guessing something has to be wrong with my code...

Comment: sql server keeps as much data as it can in RAM. so if it can it will keep the 1Gb Lob in memory. to test this simply restart the sql server service, check the mem, reread the varbinary column and check mem again.

Comment: I just tested with a non-local SQL server, and you were right. Nothing buffered on my end, but sometimes a little on the server.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

The FileStream class buffers input and output. You can call the Flush() method after each update to clear the internal buffers.

To be clear, it will only buffer up to the buffer size (4 KB).

In this case, I think your culprit is SqlExpress. When I executed your code and wrote to my local copy of SqlExpress, the memory usage by the sqlsrvr process jumped by around 1 GB. When I wrote to a non-local database, my memory usage remained flat.

Comment: That seemed to help a little bit. However it looked like it still added 50% to 80% of the file size to memory... :(

Comment: Same here, when using a non-local SQL server. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try GC.Collect() they may be dependencies waiting to be collected.