# inserting a File as Varbinary(MAX) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, varbinary, varbinarymax

I'm trying to insert values to my table which contains varbinary(MAX), and the file I try to insert is byte[]

```
 public DataTable add1(string docName , byte[] doc)
{
    DBAdaptor db = new DBAdaptor();
    string query = "INSERT INTO [Document]    (DocumentName, DocumentData) OUTPUT       inserted.DocumentID VALUES        (N'" + docName + "' , " + doc + ")";
    return db.QueryRide(query);
}
```

and I get this exception :

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ''.

and here is the function which execute my query:

```
public DataTable QueryRide(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;        
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

how can I insert this byte[] to my table? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Sequentially doing UPDATE .WRITE on VarBinary column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942609/sql-sequentially-doing-update-write-on-varbinary-column)

Comment: You should **always** use **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL statement!! Otherwise, you're at a high risk of SQL injection attacks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static int insertDocument(string name, byte[] data)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandText = @"
            INSERT INTO [Document] (DocumentName, DocumentData)
            OUTPUT      inserted.DocumentID
            VALUES      (@Name, @Data)";
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", data);
        cn.Open();
        return (int)cm.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works pretty well. but what are the differences? and when I want to Select this should I write some query like this? thanks again :)

Comment: I don't know how that DBAdaptor works (is it native?), but internally it should do same thing. Also, always use parametrized queries, just like marc_s said

Comment: DBAdaptor has a function like what I just added above.

Comment: Also note, in this case, you just need an integer, not a data table